# Is the sum of $f(x)+g(x)$ an infinitely large function? Where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both infinitely large and $g = o(f)$ (with $x \to +0$)

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure that such notation is used everywhere (I hope it is) so just in case I'll explain:
$$(x \to a)\ \  g=o(f) \Leftrightarrow g(x) = f(x)*\alpha(x), \ \ \lim\limits_{x\to a}{\alpha (x)} = 0$$

An infinitely large function as $x \to a$ is:
$$\forall E > 0 : \exists  \delta > 0: \forall x \ (0<|x-a| <\delta) \ \ |f(x)| > E$$

I've tried this:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to +0}{f(x)+g(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to +0}{f(x)*(1+ \alpha (x))} = \lim\limits_{x \to +0}{f(x)}*\lim\limits_{x \to +0}{(1+ \alpha (x))} = \infty* 1 = \infty$$
Where $\alpha(x)$ - in an infinitely small function.

It seems like a right solution but I don't use the fact that $g(a)$ is an infinitely large function anywhere. Therefore, I'm a bit confused. I would appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative near zero, then $f+g \ge f$ and $f+g \ge g$, so you only really need one of the functions to tend to infinity as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @angryavian Its not stated that these functions are nonnegative the limit could be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ (or both)

Comment: @FoorgyInfifcio If one goes to $\infty$ and the other to $-\infty$, you can't conclude anything about the limit of the sum. It could be any finite value, could be $\infty,-\infty$, or could not exist.

Comment: @DonThousand well yes, but how does this contradict with my proof? Maybe the $o(f)$ condition makes these functions of the same sign?

Comment: @FoorgyInfifcio Then you should clarify what "infinitely large function" means, since you yourself have used "$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \infty$" in your own proof.

Comment: @angryavian Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor modification of your argument to handle Don Thousand's comment about cancellations. Also, I will assume "infinitely large" means $|f(x)| \to \infty$ rather than $f(x) \to \infty$.

Suppose $|f(x)| \to \infty$ and $|g(x)| \to \infty$ and $|g(x)/f(x)| \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$. Then

Then
$$|f(x) + g(x)| = |f(x)| |1 + g(x)/f(x)|
\ge |f(x)| (1 - |g(x)/f(x)|).$$
Taking the limit as $x \to 0^+$ and recalling $|f(x)| \to \infty$ and $|g(x)/f(x)| \to 0$ shows that the above quantity tends to $\infty$. You are right that we didn't need the fact that $|g(x)| \to \infty$ (since the final claim holds even if $g$ doesn't satisfy this).

Comment: So if $|f(x)| \to \infty$ than $(f+o(f)) \to \infty$ regardles of what $o(f)$ is